# AWS DynamoDb : Pricing for On-demand Indexes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I need to create a `secondary index` on my `DynamoDb` table. For this table, I have set the read/write capacity mode to `On-demand`.

To query the data based on a particular column in the table, I want to create an index. ( this column is sort key, so I won't be able to perform queries only on this column)

When I created the `index` through the DynamoDB console, by default the read capacity for this index is `"on-demand"`.

I want to confirm how the pricing works for this index.

I was referring to this page -
https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/

Will it be based on number of read and write operations on this index? 
I am assuming  there will be no fixed cost (like provisioned capacity).

Answer (score 0):

I did a small experiment.

I created one table with on-demand capacity mode and another with provisioned capacity mode.

I created indexes on each of these table.

On the table with provisioned capacity mode, I could create an index with provisioned capacity mode only.

On the on-demand capacity mode, I was able to create an index with only on-demand capacity mode.

So I think my understanding is correct.

**When we create an index with on-demand capacity mode, the pricing depends upon the number of writes and reads to the table and the index.**